# pygtk: How to set the height of pop-up window in gtk.EntryCompletion

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I use gtk.EntryCompletion to implement the autocomletion function.
But the list is so long that the pop-up window touches the bottom of screen.
And I cant find the method of set the height of pop-up window in doc of pygtk.
How to set the height of pop-up window in gtk.EntryCompletion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to gtk.EntryCompletion widgets, but for cell like widgets you can control their height with the `cell.set_fixed_height_from_font(True)` method.

Look at the `gtk.CellRendererText` API for details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve the problem using `gtk.EntryCompletion.set_minimum_key_length` to prevent long list of suggestions.